# What is the URL of my website?

Tags: url, dns, ip

I have a website on a server. In this server I have Moodle installed working with LAMP stack. I can access my website by using the ip. `http://123.123.123.123`

My question, what is the URL of this website? I am not using any DNS and the website has no name. I am ok with that, i don't really need one.

The IP address would be the number that identifies my server `123.123.123.123`, is the URL the IP with the protocol? `http://123.123.123.123` ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to own up to having that website?

Comment: I ask because it has malicious content.  I was blocked by a proxy service because of a botnet at that address.

Comment: @Back2Basics 123.123.123.123 is not the real IP of my website, its an example of an IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL is a protocol identifier followed by a hostname.  So in your case, since you do not have DNS set up then your hostname is your IP address.

So, yes, the URL for HTTP traffic to your website would be `http://123.123.123.123/`

If it were over FTP it'd be `ftp://123.123.123.123/` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `http://123.123.123.123` as the URL. If this is a server on your internal network, you will need to set up your own lookup to provide a human-readable name.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [URI standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/std66), which is currently [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

[Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) defines that a URI consists of `scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]`, and that the `hier-part` can consist of `"//" authority path-abempty`. [Section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2) defines that `authority` consists of `[ userinfo "@" ] host [ ":" port ]`. [Section 3.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2) defines what `host` can be:

```
host = IP-literal / IPv4address / reg-name
```

So the `host` can be:

- an `IP-literal` (an IP address enclosed in square brackets),
- an `IPv4address` (an IP address in dotted-decimal form), or
- a `reg-name` (e.g. a domain name like `example.com`).

The IP address from your example, 123.123.123.123, would be in dotted-decimal form, so it’s an `IPv4address`.

Combining the above mentioned definitions for your case, the URI syntax would be:

```
scheme ":" "//" [ userinfo "@" ] IPv4address [ ":" port ] path-abempty [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
```

Removing optional components, we get:

```
scheme ":" "//" IPv4address path-abempty
```

As `http` is a valid `scheme` name (see [section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1)), and `path-abempty` can be empty (see [section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3)), this is a valid URI:

```
http://123.123.123.123
```

You might want to link to the variant with the trailing slash, as this form is required for HTTP requests (see [RFC 2616: 3.2.2 http URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.2.2)):

```
http://123.123.123.123/
```